# Getting the THREAD_ID using Telephony.Threads class is not working anymore

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to work as a default messaging app, and for that I have to handle incoming and outgoing SMS myself. When you insert an SMS into the DB, you have to specify the `THREAD_ID`. While browsing through the `Telephony` class I found this function

```
/**
     * This is a single-recipient version of {@code getOrCreateThreadId}.
     * It's convenient for use with SMS messages.
     * @param context the context object to use.
     * @param recipient the recipient to send to.
     * @hide
     */
    public static long getOrCreateThreadId(Context context, String recipient) {
        Set<String> recipients = new HashSet<String>();

        recipients.add(recipient);
        return getOrCreateThreadId(context, recipients);
    }

    /**
     * Given the recipients list and subject of an unsaved message,
     * return its thread ID.  If the message starts a new thread,
     * allocate a new thread ID.  Otherwise, use the appropriate
     * existing thread ID.
     *
     * <p>Find the thread ID of the same set of recipients (in any order,
     * without any additions). If one is found, return it. Otherwise,
     * return a unique thread ID.</p>
     * @hide
     */
    public static long getOrCreateThreadId(
            Context context, Set<String> recipients) {
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = THREAD_ID_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
        ...
        ...
```

Now the function is hidden by `@hide` (I guess). I can't access it anymore. I can replicate the functionality in my code, but wanted to know the right way to get `THREAD_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Threads class for getting thread ids for recipients

```
     import java.util.HashSet;
     import java.util.Set;
     import java.util.regex.Matcher;
     import java.util.regex.Pattern;

     import android.content.Context;
     import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.net.Uri;
     import android.provider.BaseColumns;
     import android.text.TextUtils;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.util.Patterns;

    public final class Threads {
    private static final String[] ID_PROJECTION = { BaseColumns._ID };
    private static final String STANDARD_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private static final Uri THREAD_ID_CONTENT_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://mms-sms/threadID");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/"), "conversations");
    public static final Uri OBSOLETE_THREADS_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            CONTENT_URI, "obsolete");
    public static final Pattern NAME_ADDR_EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("\\s*(\"[^\"]*\"|[^<>\"]+)\\s*<([^<>]+)>\\s*");

    public static final int COMMON_THREAD = 0;
    public static final int BROADCAST_THREAD = 1;

    // No one should construct an instance of this class.
    private Threads() {
    }

    /**
     * This is a single-recipient version of getOrCreateThreadId. It's
     * convenient for use with SMS messages.
     */
    public static long getOrCreateThreadId(Context context, String recipient) {
        Set<String> recipients = new HashSet<String>();

        recipients.add(recipient);
        return getOrCreateThreadId(context, recipients);
    }

    /**
     * Given the recipients list and subject of an unsaved message, return its
     * thread ID. If the message starts a new thread, allocate a new thread ID.
     * Otherwise, use the appropriate existing thread ID.
     * 
     * Find the thread ID of the same set of recipients (in any order, without
     * any additions). If one is found, return it. Otherwise, return a unique
     * thread ID.
     */
    public static long getOrCreateThreadId(Context context,
            Set<String> recipients) {
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = THREAD_ID_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();

        for (String recipient : recipients) {
            if (isEmailAddress(recipient)) {
                recipient = extractAddrSpec(recipient);
            }

            uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("recipient", recipient);
        }

        Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();
        // if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "getOrCreateThreadId uri: " + uri);

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, ID_PROJECTION,
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getLong(0);
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

    public static String extractAddrSpec(String address) {
        Matcher match = NAME_ADDR_EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(address);

        if (match.matches()) {
            return match.group(2);
        }
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the address is an email address
     * 
     * @param address
     *            the input address to be tested
     * @return true if address is an email address
     */
    public static boolean isEmailAddress(String address) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address)) {
            return false;
        }

        String s = extractAddrSpec(address);
        Matcher match = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(s);
        return match.matches();
    }
}
```